# R distinguishing between batch and interactive mode

Tags: r, batch-processing

I would like to have a condition in my code which allows me to distinguish if the code is running in Batch or interactive mode (via console). It would be something like this:

```
if (interactive mode) {do this} else if (Batch mode) {do that}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `interactive` function. For example, executing this from a terminal

```
Rscript -e 'cat(interactive())'
```

returned `FALSE` for me, while executing `interactive()` from my RStudio session returned `TRUE`.