# why does kable not print when used within a function in rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have to repeat certain outputs in many rmarkdown reports and want to write a function to use for this.

Calling a function outputs plots ok when I knit the rmd file but not kable data frames.

For example

````
---
title: "Markdown example"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Markdown example
```{r mtcars}
make_outputs <- function(){
  knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
  plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
  hist(mtcars$cyl)
}

make_outputs()

```
````

Displays the plots but not the kable table.

Comment: I suppose during knitting R is not in interactive mode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196406/r-distinguishing-between-batch-and-interactive-mode

Comment: `print(knitr::kable(head(mtcars)))` should solve the problem. Your function does not return the table.

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. Although the print method doesn't format the table as I expected so I will have to investigate that.

Comment: You also have to use `results = 'asis'` in the code chunk when using print on kable

Comment: Using `results = 'asis'` isn't working for me (the output is just text, not a table). Is anyone else continuing to have this problem?

Comment: results = 'asis' doesn't work for me either, the nicely formatted table is converted to two columns of unformatted numbers.  since as.data.frame also breaks the table format, I'm stuck.

Comment: you can try this hope this will help.```pander(mtcars,row.names=F,style="grid")```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by using `print` to print the kable output, setting the `results="asis"` of the code chunk and then using `kable_styling` from package `kableExtra`.

This works for me:

````
```{r mtcars, results='asis'}

library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

make_outputs <- function(){
  print(kable_styling(kable(head(mtcars))))
  plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
  hist(mtcars$cyl)
}

make_outputs()
```
````

Comment: This is nice, but not really satisfying solution... 1. it requires an extra package `kableExtra`. 2. `kableExtra` has enormous list of dependencies, most of them are unnecessary and could be either removed or moved to Suggests. 3. that implies `kableExtra` is not well maintained. Solution is not acceptable for me due to 2. and 3. See https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/391

Comment: I can achieve required output by defining needed kable calls in extra re-usable chunk with `{r tbls, eval=FALSE}` and then just refer to it with `{r chnk, ref.label="tbls"}`. This is hacky workaround to use chunks like functions. Still it is much better than extra dependency like `kableExtra`.

Answer (score 4):

Using a return statement with all objects in a list can help here, You can try `recordPlot` or `plot` from base R to solve your problem, By putting each of these plots in list, I managed to get the plots along with your table. Changed your code a bit in return statement to plot each of the plots along with tables like this.

**Option1:**
Using list in return with all the objects binded together without using lapply in function call

````
---
title: "Markdown example"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Markdown example
```{r mtcars}
make_outputs <- function(){

  return(list(hist(mtcars$cyl), 
              knitr::kable(head(mtcars)),
  plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)))
}

make_outputs()

```
````

Another version (In case you don't want the code to print `hist` output to your html then you can use below function to suppress it.

```
make_outputs <- function(){

  h1 <- plot(hist(mtcars$cyl, plot=FALSE))
  h2 <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
  h3 <- plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)

  return(list(h1, h2, h3))
}
```

**Option2:**
Another (better version by using `invisible` function on `lapply` to suppress NULL printing, then using **results**='asis' option in the markdown settings as below gives a clean output than earlier.

````
---
title: "Markdown example"
output: html_document
---

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir= normalizePath('..'))
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = FALSE)

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Markdown example
```{r mtcars, results='asis'}
make_outputs <- function(){

  return(list(plot(hist(mtcars$cyl, plot =FALSE)), 
              knitr::kable(head(mtcars)),
  plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)))
}

invisible(lapply(make_outputs(), print))

```
````

This has given me a histogram, a scatter plot and a table in the knitted html document. Hope this helps, Not sure though if you wanted this way. Please let me know in case you wanted in any other way.

Comment: does it allow to render two kable() from single function?

Comment: @jangorecki, it is doing alright, I have added one more statement : `knitr::kable(tail(mtcars))` and it showing me two tables, please check at your end, I am also able to add two different tables , you need to change this line: `  {r sample , results='asis'}
make_outputs <- function(){

  return(list(plot(hist(mtcars$cyl, plot =FALSE)), 
              knitr::kable(head(mtcars)),
              knitr::kable(tail(iris)),
  plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)))
} `

Comment: thanks, will wait few days before giving bounty in case there would be a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be related to `knitr::kable` incorrectly detecting the environment for the printing when it is embedded inside a function.  This interferes with its ability to correctly figure out how to format.  We can hack around this by placing the object to print in the top level environment before we print it.

````
---
title: "Markdown example"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
print_kable = function(x) {
  print(kable_print_output <<- x)
  cat('\n')
}
```

# Markdown example
```{r mtcars, results='asis'}
make_outputs <- function() {
  print_kable(knitr::kable(head(mtcars)))
  plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
  print_kable(knitr::kable(tail(mtcars)))
  }

make_outputs()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar working by

- moving the knitr::kable(head(mtcars)) inside a return() at the end of the function.
- including results = 'asis'

e.g.

````
---
title: "Markdown example"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Markdown example
```{r  results = 'asis'}
make_outputs <- function(){

print(plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl))
print(hist(mtcars$cyl))

return(knitr::kable(head(mtcars)))
}

make_outputs()

```
````

If you use ggplot for plots, you will need to wrap your plot inside print()

Comment: if you want to render 2+ tables from a function then it is not applicable